# Create a wrapper around bash using a bash function

Tags: bash, shell, command-history

I am kinda wary of messing with bash history settings and I just want to write my own custom bash history. I thought about using a bash function like this:

```
bash(){

  # write to a custom history file manually
  echo "$@" >> $HOME/my_bash_history

  command bash "$@" 

}

export -f bash;
```

but this doesn't quite work - what happens is that the `command bash` takes over, and things no longer go through the bash function. I need all stdin to bash to go through this bash function in order for everything to be written to a custom file. Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

What you want is a `DEBUG` trap (run before each command) or possibly a `PROMPT_COMMAND` (run before each prompt).

The trap is closer to your attempt.  The basic concept is outlined in [Does bash have a hook that is run before executing a command?](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command) and a polished turnkey version exists as [bash-preexec](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec).

According to its author, bash-preexec is used by [Bashhub](https://bashhub.com/) to provide "bash history in the cloud," so I'm sure it's up to the task of "bash history in a file."

Comment: **WARNING** : If you arge going to use BashHub I would suggest running your own server using the software at https://github.com/nicksherron/bashhub-server . Otherwise you can not be sure that your history is private.

Comment: Well said and, to be clear, I was recommending only bash-preexec and citing Bashub as a reference.  Putting bash history in the cloud is probably not a good idea at all.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to implement something equivalent to [this "eternal history"](https://debian-administration.org/article/543/Bash_eternal_history):

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%s "
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND ; }"'echo $$ $USER \
           "$(history 1)" >> ~/.bash_eternal_history'
```

The core idea is that `history 1` (in bash) lists the last line given to bash.

```
$ echo "$(history 1)"
12766  2019-05-31T20:14:44+0000 echo "$(history 1)"
```

Which actually only has a meaningful value (not the same line) inside an script.

And; `PROMPT_COMMAND` executes the `history` command for each new line given to bash.

IMO: It doesn't seem to be a good idea to name a function `bash`.